# Solving systems of multivariate equations

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations, finite-fields, multivariate-polynomial

I am new to the topic and I am working with the multivariate systems of equations over finite fields. My goal is to solve them. I know that in general the problem of solving such systems is NP-hard. However, there are certain attacks that can solve such systems.

Suppose I work with the first polynomial in my system of $k$ equations in $k$ variables. In my understanding, I can always fix one variable, say $x_0$ and treat the rest as coefficients. That would create a univariate polynomial in $x_0$. Given that I can solve such univariate polynomial, the roots will be functions of the remaining variables. That is $x_0 = f(x_1, \dots, x_k)$. I can then go ahead and substitute $x_0$ in the next polynomial in the system for the expression $f(x_1, \dots, x_k)$. That would reduce the number of variables I am working with by one. If I keep in this fashion, at the end I will get a univariate equation. Suppose that I can solve it, then I solved my system of multivariate equations.

I was wondering if my analysis is incorrect and if I perhaps am describing a well-known attack, then I will highly appreciate any references on this attack.

Thank you!

Comment: The catch is that $f$ need not be expressible in terms of polynomials. What would be $f$, if the first equation were something like
$$x_0^7+x_0^5=1+x_1+x_1^{11}?$$
I know that every function from a finite field to itself can be written as a polynomial. But here we don't necessarily get a function at all. For some choices of $x_1$ there may be several solutions for $x_0$; for some others there will be none.

Comment: More importantly, even if it should happen that there is single $x_0$ to each choice of the remaining variables, writing that solution as a polynomial may require going through the entire search space. That is, brute force, violating the goal of polynomial complexity.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I agree, there are cases when fixing a single variable $x_0$ will not necessarily produce a polynomial that can be solved and the roots to be written in terms of other variables.

Comment: A way of working on a system of polynomial equations is to use [Gröbner bases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6bner_basis), systematically eliminatin variables A) in a prescribed order, and B) to the extent possible. I think this is the closest thing to what you have in mind. Part B in particular requires a longer explanation (and I'm not the right person to explain it). Some people have posted youtube videos about it.

Comment: (cont'd) Like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I5PFIJbSRTc). Caveat: I did not check the content of that one, it just came up in the search engine. If you want to restrct the variables to the field $\Bbb{F}_q$ then you simply add more equations to the set of polynomials before finding a Gröbner basis: $x_i^q-x_i=0$ for all $i$.

Comment: Gröbner bases are not a magical tool for solving everything. It is possible that the first equations popping out are unwieldy. Alas, I don't know this stuff well enough to say anything about why they do not settle NP-hard problems.

Comment: More about that [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3061360/11619).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen thank you for the suggestion! I am interested in the case when the variables are restricted to the finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$. Could you provide a reference or elaborate on finding the Gröbner basis $x_i^q-x_j = 0$ for all $i$. Do you mean the polynomials in the Gröbner basis will have this form?

Comment: No, I meant that those equations should be added to the system you started with. Then find a Gröbner basis of the ideal.

Answer (score 1):

There is no computationally useful way in which the roots of the univariate polynomial "are functions of the remaining variables". I assume that by "polynomials" you include those of any degree.

Anyway, in order to understand how the solution set is computed, one might want to learn some computational algebraic geometry.

Comment: In any case, there are only $q^k$ solutions to check by brute force. Is there a reason why you want a more efficient method?

Comment: You think brute force is feasible if $q\approx 2^{300}$ and $k=7$?

Comment: Of course not. I was asking what the OP's aims and wishes are. Maybe this was just intended to be a fun project for the OP

Comment: Sure. Sorry about coming through a bit cranky. The upvote is mine because you summarized nicely what needs to be said.

Comment: I see, no worries

Comment: Thank you for the answer! My interest comes purely from reading a few papers on multivariate cryptography and the underlying hard mathematical problems. Just trying to wrap my head around the possible ways to solve systems of multivariate polynomials over finite fields.